# Place text midway along right-angled arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have two nodes that are offset both horizontally and vertically. I am connecting them using a right-angled arrow (there might be a proper name for these that I haven't found). When I add a node along the arrow using `midway`, it doesn't place it where I want. In the case I show below, it would ideally be placed midway along the horizontal portion of the arrow. Is there a way to achieve this? For now, I have been using `xshift` and eyeballing the midpoint.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=1mm}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[] (B) at (5,-2) {B};
    \node[] (C) at (2.5,-2) {C};
    \draw[->] (B.south) -- +(0,-0.5) -| (A.south) node [midway, below, anchor=north] {Midway};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Actual result:
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: Try `pos=0.25` instead of `midway`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit That seems to work, but why?

Comment: @jared Because it is programmed that way. You're placing a node along the `-|` path operation. [The midway point is exactly at the kink.](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.8) The `-` part goes from 0 to 0.5 and the `|` goes from 0.5 to 1. That way, 0.25 (or `near start`) is halfway for the `-` and 0.75 (`near end`) is halfway for the `|` part.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah, so if I understand correctly, tikz sees what I made as two lines, a vertical line that goes from the `B.south` to -0.5 below it and a kinked line that ends at `A.south`. Since I placed the node after the kinked line and said `midway`, it saw two portions to the kink (vertical and horizontal) and placed it at that intersection. By specifying `pos=0.25`, tikz breaks the kinked line into four segments: two parts for the `-` line and two parts for the left `|` line. It then places the text at the end of the first part of the `-` line. Correct?

Comment: This is correct. When you use the `|-` or `-|` argument for your path, the breaking point is considered `midway`. Then you have to take this in account when placing nodes or coordinates on this broken line. Especially, if the two parts are not equal in distance, you will not have a proportional placement all along the broken line, but only proportional on each part.